# Dependency Property Callback method is not invoked upon change of Data type member value. How can we achieve this?

Tags: wpf

```
Public class MyView
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontPaddingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FontPadding", typeof(ThicknessPaddings), 
        typeof(MyView), new UIPropertyMetadata(new ThicknessPaddings() { 
        Left = "1", Right = "1" }, new PropertyChangedCallback(FontPaddingChanged)));
}
```

And in the UI xaml file i have bound it like :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FontPadding.Left, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

But when i change the Left value in UI my callback method "FontPaddingChanged" is not getting triggered. please suggest where i am doing wrong.

I Created a custom class

```
public class ThicknessPaddings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    private string left;
    private string right; 
    public string Left
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.left; 
        }
        set
        {
            this.left = value;
            this.OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Left");
        }
    }

    public string Right
    {
        get { return this.right; }
        set
        {
            this.right = value;
            this.OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Right");
        }
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude... you should read over your question *before* you post it... some of your code was missing. I've now fixed your dodgy formatting so that everyone can see it.

Comment: Thanks Sheridan, i will take care hence forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FontPaddingProperty` calls the `PropertyChangedCallback` only if the property is given another `ThicknessPaddings` object. In your case you change a property of current `FontPaddingProperty`'s object, not the object itself so the only thing that is getting raised is the .NET `PropertyChanged` Event inside your object.