# Dependency property property change callback not triggered when internal property of custom type changed

Tags: c#, wpf

Now that's a confusing title... maybe I can explain better in detail: I have a dependency property of a custom type called ChartTheme:

```
public NewChartTheme ChartTheme
{
    get
    {
        return (NewChartTheme)GetValue(ChartThemeProperty);
    }
    set
    { 
        SetValue(ChartThemeProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartThemeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
                                     (
                                      "ChartTheme",
                                      typeof(NewChartTheme),
                                      typeof(RadChartViewUserControlView),
                                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() 
                                          { PropertyChangedCallback = UpdateChartingTheme }
                                     );
```

Within the custom type, NewChartTheme, there are numerous properties. Basically, I want the DP callback to trigger whenever one of those properties changes. I would think that the callback function would fire because the object itself changes whenever one of its properties changes but apparently that isn't the case.

Any suggestions on how to get this property change to bubble up?

**EDIT**

With respect to Rohit Vats' answer, I implemented his code with one caveat. NewChartTheme is a model in a MVVM pattern. Because of that, it doesn't implement INPC. I exposed the ViewModel (which does implement INPC through base classes) and modified the code accordingly. It's a little hackish but I would think it should work. However, the MainWindow_PropertyChanged method never gets hit when a property is changed in the VM. Here is my altered code:

```
private static void UpdateChartingTheme(DependencyObject sender,
                                    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    IUserInteractionService iuis =
        AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IUserInteractionService>();
    NewChartTheme ct = (sender as RadChartViewUserControlView).ChartTheme;
    NewChartThemeViewModel vm = (sender as RadChartViewUserControlView).ChartThemeVM;

    if (args != null && args.Property != null && sender != null && ct != null)
    {
        vm = new NewChartThemeViewModel(iuis, ct);

        if (args.OldValue != null)
        {
            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)vm).PropertyChanged -=
                                                  MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
        }
        if (args.NewValue != null)
        {
            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)vm).PropertyChanged +=
                                                  MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}

public static void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadChartViewUserControlView chartView = sender as RadChartViewUserControlView;
    if (chartView.ChartTheme != null && chartView.Data != null)
        chartView.Create2DCharting(chartView);
}
```

I am embarrassed to say that I've read on the subject over the past day and am at a loss why this code isn't working.

**EDIT 2**

My final code that works great thanks to Rohit Vats. Thanks so much:

```
private static void UpdateChartingTheme(DependencyObject sender, 
                                        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.OldValue != null)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)args.OldValue).PropertyChanged += (sender1, args1) => MainWindow_PropertyChanged(sender1, args1, sender as RadChartViewUserControlView);
    }

    if (args.NewValue != null)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)args.NewValue).PropertyChanged += 
            (sender1, args1) => 
                MainWindow_PropertyChanged(sender1, args1, sender as RadChartViewUserControlView);
    }
}        

static void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e, RadChartViewUserControlView userControl)
{
    if (userControl != null && userControl.Data != null)
        userControl.Create2DCharting(userControl);
}
```

Comment: I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122138/dependency-property-callback-method-is-not-invoked-upon-change-of-data-type-memb?rq=1 in which the answer tells why but doesn't tell how to achieve what we want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As like you mentioned in comment that ***Callback won't be called unless property changed for dependency property***.

But anyhow, there is a way to achieve that with following steps:

- When value is set for this DP first time, you can **hook `PropertyChanged` event of class NewChartTheme** (assuming you have implemented INPC on this class and raising PropertyChanged event whenever any property is changed).
- Put your code in PropertyChanged handler and you are good to go.
- Also make sure, you **unhook PropertyChanged event whenever actual DP changes to some other instance** (just to avoid any memory leaks)

That being said here is the code what i mentioned in above points:

```
private static void UpdateChartingTheme(DependencyObject sender, 
                                        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
   if (args.OldValue != null)
   {
       ((INotifyPropertyChanged)args.OldValue).PropertyChanged -= 
                                             MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
   }
   if (args.NewValue != null)
   {
       ((INotifyPropertyChanged)args.NewValue).PropertyChanged += 
                                            MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
   }
}

static void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your work here.
}
```

Comment: I've edited the original post which is basically a reply to your answer. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying with that posted code (making no sense at all)? Creating new instance `vm = new NewChartThemeViewModel(iuis, ct);` in propertyChanged which is not actual instance where property changed. And what makes you think that model class cannot implement `INPC`? It's perfectly valid to have that on model class.

Comment: INPC gets implemented in the vm which is our typical way of doing things. the model in this case is getting serialized so if memory serves INPC would be a problem. (I could be wrong about that.) As I began typing out the response about the view model instance, the problem hit me. You obviously saw through my idiocy at first glance but I was stuck with tunnel vision.

Comment: I see no issue in implementing INPC but in case that's your project constraint that's fine. However, still why to make new instance? Why not to hook on actual vm you get here - `NewChartThemeViewModel vm = (sender as RadChartViewUserControlView).ChartThemeVM;`.

Comment: `NewChartThemeViewModel vm = (sender as RadChartViewUserControlView).ChartThemeVM` doesn't contain the view model. It is a property in the usercontrol that I created to store the view model that didn't exist before I tried to implement your code. I am taking advantage of pass by reference since this is a static method. I can't simply say `this.ChartThemeVM = new NewChartThemeViewModel(iuis, ct);`It's a hack way to do it I know but I just wanted to see the code work at this point. But it's all a moot point as you pointed out, this code isn't going to work.

Comment: It should be instead `(sender as RadChartViewUserControlView).ChartThemeVM = new NewChartThemeViewModel(iuis, ct);` and i assume propertyChanged event is raised properly on any property change. Make sure you hook PropertyChanged on same instance of ViewModel where property is changing.

Comment: OK. I got it working. I did go ahead and implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the model. As I expected there was a serialization issue. It was easily rectified by marking the event with the appropriate attribute as such: `[field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`  I will add my final code which is basically your code slightly modified to pass in the usercontrol instance (needed because the static method prevents referencing the usercontrol.)